# using environment variables when launching TestCafe from runner.class

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I am task with testing different languages of a site using Testcafe. Rather than writing n tests for each language, I want one testfile that requires a(n ever changing) language file.

I read a lot along the line that this was not possible, so my idea was to pack the language in question into an environment variable and translate this into the path to the required language object much like this:

```
// test.spec.js
//
const lang = require(path(__baseDir,"ressources","languages",process.env.LANG))
```

since I need to use the runner class I wanted to 'inject' the env.variable with the "startApp()" method, like so:

```
//tcRunner.js
//
const createTestCafe = require("testcafe");

const launch = async function (tests, browser) {
  const testcafe = await createTestCafe("localhost", 1337, 1338);
  const runner = await testcafe.createRunner();

  runner
    .startApp("set LANG=en-GB")
    .src("test.spec.js")
    .browsers(browser)
    .reporter("json", "reports/report.json")
    .run()
    .then(failed => {
      console.log(failed + " Tests failed");
      testcafe.close();
    });
};
```

As my posting suggests, this does not work and I was hoping you could point me into the direction (even an alternative one) to avoid writing hundreds of tests per language.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the 'LANG' envirnoment variable before running tests.

```js
//tcRunner.js
//
const createTestCafe = require("testcafe");

const launch = async function (tests, browser) {
  const testcafe = await createTestCafe("localhost", 1337, 1338);
  const runner = await testcafe.createRunner();

  process.env.LANG = 'en';

  runner
    .src("test.spec.js")
    .browsers(browser)
    .reporter("json", "reports/report.json")
    .run()
    .then(failed => {
      console.log(failed + " Tests failed");
      testcafe.close();
    });
};
```

Comment: That seems so simple, I feel a little dumb for asking. For me, environment variables were something set on the outside and "read only" in JS. After experimenting a little I want to add that

`const lang = require(`../lang/${process.env.LANG}.lang`);` in test.spec.js won't work, but

`const l = process.env.LANG;
 const lang = require(`../lang/${l}.lang`);`

will. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the charmingly working answer above, I found another solution by

`//test.spec.js
 const lang = require("../lang.js")`

and in the runner function just

`fs.copyFileSync(path.join(__dirname, "lang", lang + ".lang.js"), "lang.js")`